# window.history.forward() no funciona en Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Tengo la función : window.history.forward();

```js
function dontback(){ 
   window.history.forward();
}
```

```html
<body onload="dontback();">
<form blablabla >
```

La uso para que el usuario no pueda retroceder, en Chrome  e Internet Explorer funciona, impidiendo que el usuario pueda retroceder, pero en Firefox no funciona.¿ Qué debo hacer ?

Edito: la versión de Firefox que uso es 56.0

Answer (score 1):

Solo cambiar la forma en que verifica la `Load`

```
function dontback(){ 
   window.history.forward();
}    
window.onload = dontback;// En Lugar del HTML
```

Comment: llevo varios intento y no consigo hacerlo funcionar en chrome /explorer ni firefox. haciendo eso de poniéndolo en el html

<html onload="dontback()";
y con html windows.onload="dontback()";

Podrías ser más específico .. soy nuevo en esto XD
Gracias.